# Using named capture groups in SiriProxy plugin

Tags: ruby, siri

I'm working on a SiriProxy plugin. I am trying to move all of the regular expression into a configuration file. There can be multiple phrases (i.e. regular expressions) that trigger the same command, and the regular expressions need to capture specific values to call underlying functions.

I might have a command that records animal-related behaviour, for which I want to use 2 phrases as follows:

```
the <mouse> was chased by the <cat>
the <cat> chased the mouse
```

where "cat" and "mouse" are the 2 parameters. The cat is the chaser and the mouse is the chasee, and the 2 phrases use these in a different order. My goal (using the siriproxy plugin framework, remember) is to make the order of the captured parameters irrelevant, and so I always know in the captured terms, who is the chaser and chasee.

So, my 2 regular expressions look like this:

```
/the (?<chasee>\w+) was chased by the (?<chaser>\w+)/i
/the (?<chaser>\w+) chased the (?<chasee>\w+)/i
```

they do correctly capture the 2 terms, but they care captured in order. Using the SiriProxy framework, we use the listen_for command, and I can get this to work:

```
listen_for (/the (?<chasee>\w+) was chased by the (?<chaser>\w+)/i) { | chasee, chaser | record_animal_behaviour(chasee, chaser) }
listen_for (/the (?<chaser>\w+) chased the (?<chasee>\w+)/i) { | chaser, chasee | record_animal_behaviour(chasee, chaser) }
```

But the order of the chasee and chaser have to be swapped round between the | characters. I want this to be standarised, so that it doesn't matter what the regular expression phrase is and how it orders the parameters.

When I try swapping the parameters, the values also get swapped around, resulting in the wrong animal becoming the chasee and cahser. It is as-if the listen_for command is not "honouring" the named capture groups as it passes them through to the function call, and just going on order instead.

Has anyone tackled something similar, either using SiriProxy, or just using Ruby regexps in general? I don't know if there is something I can do with the regular expression itself to force the terms out in order, or a different way to use the listen_for command to achieve this.

Comment: Please try to make your question more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Having spent a few more hours digging through the SiriProxy code, I think I have figured out the answer to my own problem...

In the version of SiriProxy I am using, the "process" in Cora::Plugin works using the MatchData#capture method, meaning the parameters are simply presented in order, and no looks like no real support for named capture groups...certain not in the way I want to use them.

Overriding this process method in my plugin to access the MatchData object using it's array-style interface (see: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/MatchData.html#method-i-5B-5D) seems to do what I need. So, I'll just figure out the best way to implement in an extensible manner and should be sorted.